# ask for user input again if input is wrong without getting the wrong value in the list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, input

Why does `elif b!= 0 and b!= 1: print (b)` not work?
the user has to put 1 or 0 in order to determine b. If the user doesn't write 1 or 0, I want the program to ask him again "is player a Computer (0) or a human (1)?" without list_2 appending the initial wrong number.

```
list_2 = []
players = int(input("number of players: ")) 
   
for i in range (players):
    a = input("name of player: ")
    b = int(input ("is player a Computer (0) or a human (1)?"))

    if b == 0:
        list_2.append([a] + [True])
      
    elif b == 1:
        list_2.append([a] + [False])

    elif b!= 0 and b!= 1:
        print (b)
         
print (list_2)
```

Comment: let's say b= 0, then your conditional evaluates to false,  because b is not equal to 1.  If b= 1, then the conditional evaluates to false since b not equal to 0.  I think your conditional should be ```elif b!= 0 or b!= 1```.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap that section of input in a `while True` loop. break the loop when the input is correct, otherwise keep looping for more input.

```
while True:
    b = int(input ("is player a Computer (0) or a human (1)?"))
    if b == 0:
        # player is a computer ...
        # do computer stuff
        break
    elif b == 1:
        # player is a human ...
        # do human stuff
        break
    else:
        print("That was not 1 or 0.  Please try again")
```

Answer (score 0):

Because elif is not a loop , compiler just checks the condition and then it moves forward executing the statement.

You can solve this by just adding a ***while loop *** before first if condition like this :

for i in range (players):
a = input("name of player: ")
b = int(input ("is player a Computer (0) or a human (1)?"))

```
while (b!=0 and b!=1): # Checking if b is not equal to both '0' and '1'
    b = int(input ("is player a Computer (0) or a human (1)?"))
    
if b == 0:
    list_2.append([a] + [True])
  
elif b == 1:
    list_2.append([a] + [False])

elif b!= 0 and b!= 1:
    print (b)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to split your code and create a new `checkInput` function as implemented below.

```js
list_2 = []
players = int(input("number of players: ")) 

def checkInput(value):
    if value == 0:
        list_2.append([a] + [True])
        return True
      
    elif value == 1:
        list_2.append([a] + [False])
        return True
        
    else:
       return False


for i in range (players):
    check = False;
    a = input("name of player: ")

    while check == False:
        b = int(input ("is player a Computer (0) or a human (1)?"))
        check = checkInput(b)
        print('Please enter correct input')
    
         
            
print (list_2)
```